# Нужно ли отвечать на "старые" комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение

Ситуация такая: участник задает вопрос, я на него подробно отвечаю, далее следуют комментарии с обеих сторон. Вроде бы всё понятно, вопрос закрыт.

Но где-нибудь через пару недель, месяц, полгода участник хочет еще что-нибудь уточнить.

Если вопрос был сложным, то мне приходится всё вспоминать заново, вникать в тонкости темы, в его понимание или непонимание заданного вопроса, в свои объяснения.

Нужно ли мне это делать? Честно говоря, я считаю, что это неуважение к моему времени. Говорить  ему об этом в открытую не хочется (человек может обидеться).

Как мне поступить, может, модераторы мне помогут? Может быть, есть какие-то правила на этот счет? Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, правила, которое указывало бы, как следует поступать в описываемой вами ситуации, не существует. Думаю, что логично было бы делать то, что хочется — сайт – не рабочее место :) Так что если вам хочется ответить на комментарий к устаревшему сообщению, то сделайте это; в противном случае — не делайте.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Жаль, что нет правила, а человек сам этого не понимает. Дело не в желании, а просто времени нет, чтобы заново осмысливать тему.

Answer (score 2):

В справке прямо сказано, что автор плохо поставленного вопроса рискует остаться без ответа. Можно расширенно трактовать это так, что никто не обязан отвечать, если ему этого не хочется. Не думаю, что Ваше "молчание" в описанной ситуции может кого-то обидеть.